# Why didn't Hogwarts shut down after these type of events?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I saw this [article from Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-hogwarts-shut-down/). Wonderful article mind you, it makes me curious that those the points gathered there are very valid to the school must be shut down especially when Voldemort returned. However, I don't agree with the 9th and 5th one. In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Professor McGonagall was worried about what's happening to the students regarding the basilisk's attack.

> Students must be sent home, I'm afraid this would be the end of Hogwarts.

Though I'm not sure if she said that in the book, but that's not the point here. The point here is that danger that is happening in Hogwarts. It's so ridiculous that Hogwarts is a school that doesn't prioritize the safety of the students. Shall I put the list for you and I will just copy it from the article if you don't mind =).

1. The Chamber of Secrets opened twice

   > Good point! The first time the Chamber of Secrets was opened was when Voldemort was at school. He opened the Chamber and set the basilisk on Muggle-born students and then blamed everything on Hagrid. The school should have shut down when the attacks kept going on, but it definitely should have been shut down after Moaning Myrtle died.
   > The death of a student and the fact that other students were petrified is a good reason to shut the school down for a while. 
   > Considering the fact that the first time the Chamber of Secrets was opened that a student died, you would think it reopening a second time would be good enough reason to close the school right away. Given that Hagrid and others were alive and a part of what happened, it’s not like it was that long ago. The school should have been closed once the first attack happened and not reopened again until the monster had been identified and stopped.
2. Umbridge used Physical Punishments

   > Potterhead fans almost hated her more than the Dark Lord himself. While Voldemort was often one of the worst things to happen to Hogwarts, Umbridge was almost as bad. She might not have been in league with Voldemort at the time, but she was truly vile. She used physical torture as punishment during detentions by making students carve words into the back of their hands over and over. This is a completely wild thing to happen, and the school should have been shut down once this started happening.
3. When Voldemort possesses Quirrell

   > During Harry Potter's time at Hogwarts, there were multiple times when Voldemort and his plans to come back to power put Harry and all the other students at risk. This started early on in Harry’s first year. It was pretty ridiculous that Dumbledore housed the Sorcerer’s Stone at Hogwarts in the first place. But, after Quirrell, who had Voldemort on the back of his head, tried to kill Harry to get the stone, there should have at least been some sort of inquiry. Instead, things just went right back to normal.
4. Cedric Diggory died at the Triwizard Tournament

   > This is one of the most horrifying things that happened to a Hogwarts student during Harry’s time at the school. While Cedric didn’t actually die at the school, he did die under mysterious circumstances that were connected to a school event.The Triwizard Tournament was so dangerous anyway that it shouldn’t have been reinstated. After Cedric died, some serious consideration about the school and its safety measures should have happened.
5. When Voldemort came back to power

   > After Voldemort came back to power at the end of The Goblet of Fire, it would have been wise to just shut Hogwarts down. Of course, the Ministry didn’t actually want to admit he was back, but after it was confirmed, Hogwarts should have been shut down for a time. While lots of people insisted that being around Dumbledore was the safest place to be, clearly this isn't actually true as so many bad things happened at the school.
6. A Dark secret from a Defense against the Dark Arts Teacher

   > So many of the Defense Against the Dark Arts teachers posed a safety risk to the students. First, there was Quirrell, and then there was Lockhart who was a fraud,Lupin a werewolf,Moody who was actually a Death Eater impersonating the Auror and of course, Umbridge. While Snape is the loathsome of most students, Dumbledore needed him to accomplish the plan. Considering how many professors were horrible to the students, it would have been a good idea to shut the school down and rethink it.
7. After the Battle of Hogwarts

   > This is interesting.One of the most tragic things that ever happened at Hogwarts was the Battle of Hogwarts. This battle ended the lives of multiple people, including one who was a student at the time. The fact that the school ever reopened after this doesn't make a lot of sense.It’s basically the source of a lot of trauma for many of the students and their families, so it would make more sense to move the wizarding school to some other location.

So all of those events that gathered from Steele (the article writer) makes a valid reason to stop sending students to Hogwarts every year.

REFERENCE: https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-hogwarts-shut-down/

Comment: The because then there would be no books after the first one?

Comment: @TorstenLink that's plot convenience which doesn't make sense

Comment: How about a comparison with real life? There are schools which became victims of amok killers and they don’t get closed afterwards. When there was fear of a sniper in the US, schools didn’t close. The windows got covered and life continued. Did ever entire schools get closed because *one teacher* used physical punishments? Why should that happen in the wizard world where the ministry doesn’t even saw a problem in this, as Umbridge never got punished? It seems, you expect Hogwarts to get closed for much less than real life schools and that, when Hogwarts seems to be *the only school* in UK…

Comment: Counterpoint to #5: You're more likely to catch a disease in a hospital since that's where the sick people are. But what you're arguing is akin to saying people shouldn't go to hospitals. Yes, there are threats in Hogwarts, but there are also threats if you're somewhere else (as proven by Voldemort's destruction of the peaceful atmosphere in the wizarding world and his agenda to rid the world of mudbloods). Halting education has massive repercussions for future wizarding generations. You'll get rogue wizards and witches, untrained to properly handle magic.

Comment: @Holger Another real-life data point- People didn't call for the Pentagon to be shut down and the workers relocated after 9/11. There were even calls from many to rebuild the World Trade Center towers (ultimately deemed too costly) and resume business as usual to send a tangible message that evil had not won.

Comment: That's what they'd do in modern society, but wizarding society has different moral standards. See also [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155372/why-did-the-wizarding-society-seem-to-have-such-a-weak-view-of-civil-rights) for more details on that.

Comment: The books are predicated fundamentally on *whimsy*, remember these books are *fantasy*.

Comment: Cedric Diggory was both not on school grounds, and participating in a Ministry-run extracurricular activity (which the schools appear to have had little or no control over or input in) - his death is a reason to cancel the Triwizard Tournament, not to close Hogwarts

Comment: The books weren't written in the 21st century.

Comment: Regarding 2): Umbridge worked for the system, which saw no issue with her actions at the time. Why would a government close a school because someone appointed there by that government was carrying out government sanctioned activities?

Answer (score 106):

The writer of this Muggle article is ascribing Muggle values to the wizarding world.

The Wizarding world generally seems to accept danger far more readily then the muggle world does, a tournament is held that involves putting students in danger fighting Dragons, their loved ones are captured. They engage in a sport that sees children fly broomsticks at amazing speeds while trying to knock each other off.

Lessons also add a sense of real risk, potions class leads to mishaps, poisonings and students being transformed needing care. The infirmary is almost always treating a student or two for magical mishaps.

So given that the day-to-day life of being a wizard could, at any point, lead to a wizard facing death or worse at the hands of some creature, another wizard or just their own mistakes at spell casting then, it could be argued, the experiences at Hogwarts mean the students of Hogwarts are more prepared for the wizarding world than at any other school.

Also remember many of the events of the early books are glossed over by the Ministry of Magic, they want to cover it all up. Shutting Hogwarts would lead to questions and bring to light the events of the past few years. Dumbledore however truly believes the only way to keep his students safe is to keep them in the protective wards of the school, and any peril caused by being there, well, it's just part of the everyday fun and excitement of being a child wizard.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  In the wizards' world, all adults and children over the age of 11 carry around potential weapons of mass destruction at all times.  Many families share their homes with members of a slave race that possesses similar powers.  If anything, I found it unrealistic that closing Hogwarts was even floated as an idea during *Chamber of Secrets*; the students were already in deadly danger all the time even without a basilisk being on the loose.

Comment: @tbrookside The difference is that a deadly creature was on the prowl with *intent to kill* - Any of the teachers could probably kill scores or hundreds of students without much difficulty, but they are not *trying* to (and in fact are probably trying *not* to). It'd be the same difference in the real world between a school resource officer w/ a gun walking the halls vs. letting school continue with a known serial killer armed w/ a gun walking the halls.

Comment: @TylerH not at all. The fact is, if you want an analogy with the real world, *every child attending Hogwarts has a good chance of calling a serial killer on his mobile AND inviting him to school **by mistake***. Your perception is skewed by the incredibly safe world we are generally having in the West in the 21st century.

Comment: I think the more relevant aspect is that while magic has the capacity to cause harm beyond what non-magical people can easily appreciate, it *also* has the capacity to repair things similarly. Focusing only on magic's destructive or injurious potential misses that access to magic is a *category difference*, not a difference of degree in potential harms. An HP-style magical world isn't just a more dangerous version of the regular world, it is a *totally different setting with totally different rules*. Getting cut in half at the waist is an easily fixable annoyance in HP.

Comment: @Gnudiff Your analogy is not at all accurate. First of all, the location of the entrance is unknown, Second, the *method* to open it is unknown. Third, the *ability* to open it is exceedingly rare and not something that is known to be learn-able (though we learn later that Ron [probably via plot-skill rather than character-skill] is able to brute force the password). Fourth, all of those concerns are irrelevant anyway due to the basilisk (or in my case the serial killer) *already having been let out and about*.

Comment: @TylerH i am afraid you didn't get the point. Children wizards in HP universe each have the *ability* to summon and do all kinds of dangerous things by misfortune, accident or malevolence. Their wands can be compared to handguns or (as I did) unrestricted mobile phones for eldritch things. This is an occupational hazard for both them and the teachers and as such part of normal life there. Therefore when a dangerous killing beast is unleashed, it is just something that could happen in this setting. Therefore the response is: find and kill it. Then go on. Not, close the school.

Comment: @Upper_Case was it the case really? That somebody was literally cut in two, and afterwards mended? Don't remember anything like that in the books. And it doesn't sound feasible in HP universe. When you are cut in half you are basically dead. And as we know, bringing dead to life is not something that happens there.

Comment: @Upper_Case being cut in half would be much worse than _Sectumsempra_ cast at Malfoy by Harry. And Malfoy didn't recover fast. Were Snape not around, Malfoy would've died.

Comment: @Gnudiff It happened to a student during apparition (though I'm now unsure if it was cut-in-half-at-the-waist or leg(s)-cut-off). Anyways, it was immediately fixed by the teaching staff.

Comment: @Ruslan I'm not sure that's true. *Sectumsempra* clearly has more than mundane slashing going for it, as it took a specific countercharm of some kind to repair Malfoy's gashes (if it were cuts as from a knife, Madame Pomfrey would have had no trouble fixing it in an instant). But the specifics are not crucial to my point, which is that while magic can cause unusual harms, relative to mundane means, it also has a huge capacity to fix problems both mundane and magical. Saying it's all downside risk is flatly wrong.

Comment: @Upper_Case if I remember correctly it was not a case of, you know, somebody taking a sword and slicing somebody in half, it was more like imagine  somebody stepped a halfway through a portal -- you can see one his side in one place, and other in the other place, but there's no physical damage to the body.

Comment: @Gnudiff Um, I'm not sure you *are* remembering correctly (there's no portal, part of her body moved and part did not). The teachers certainly seemed to treat it as very serious. But those details aren't really relevant, because perfectly reattaching limbs and body sections with completely restored functionality (as if the injury never happened at all) isn't something we can do without magic (at present, anyways).

Comment: @Gnudiff I got the point, you were just wrong.

Comment: @TylerH well, I obviously disagree.

Comment: @TylerH yes children where dying in the halls of hogwarts, but Dumbledore didn’t know exactly how or why. He could have sent the students home only to find they where them picked off one by one in there houses unprotected by being grouped together. In addition measures where put in place to try and protect the students. But remember also, just outside the school live giant spiders that are not friendly, dragons and other dangerous creatures are brought in for study and lessons. I imagine over the years the odd student dying is not seen as a spectacular event.

Comment: i salute you for your empathy. it's like the 'narcirema' article. or like that episode of the practice where alan shore defends that little girl from the little girl's parents who intend to force the little girl to get married and have sex (spoiler: the judge rules in the parents' favour by denying the little girls' petition for asylum).

Comment: Except this is a fantasy world where the adults regularly put children in mortal danger with no real concerns.

Answer (score 22):

All of these are different events, and each has its own reasons for why the *school* wasn't shut down after each one. Let's go through them.

---

1. **The Chamber of Secrets**

   1a. The first time it was opened, the school was *nearly* shut down. However, after Riddle managed to pin it on Hagrid, and Hagrid got expelled (and the attacks stopped), the school was able to continue, because the "culprit" had been apprehended.

   > "You mean all these attacks, sir?" said Riddle, and Harry's heart
   >   leapt, and he moved closer, scared of missing anything.
   >   "Precisely," said the headmaster. "My dear boy, you must see how foolish it would be of me to allow you to remain at the castle when term ends. Particularly in light of the recent tragedy ... the death of that poor little girl .... You will be safer by far at your orphanage. As a matter of fact, the Ministry of Magic is even now talking about closing the school. We are no nearer locating the er - source of all this unpleasantness . . . ."
   >   Riddle's eyes had widened.
   >   "Sir - if the person was caught - if it all stopped -"
   >   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 12: "The Polyjuice Potion"</sub>

   1b. The second time it was opened, the school was again very nearly shut down.

   > "Who is it?" said Madam Hooch, who had sunk, weak-kneed, into a
   >   chair. "Which student?"
   >   "Ginny Weasley," said Professor McGonagall.
   >   Harry felt Ron slide silently down onto the wardrobe floor beside him.
   >   "We shall have to send all the students home tomorrow," said Professor McGonagall. "This is the end of Hogwarts. Dumbledore always said. . ."
   >   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter</sub>

   However, like the first time, the one responsible was found - Voldemort - and the attacks stopped, again making it safe. Once the attacks stopped, the school was deemed safe again and thus was able to continue operation.
2. **Umbridge**

   Ugh, Umbridge. **shudders** This is an isolated case of an abusive teacher.... who, if you'll remember, was there *because of the Minister of Magic*. The Ministry isn't going to shut down the school because *they themselves* put an abusive teacher there. After her... incident... at the end of the school year, she was gone and there was no longer an issue. But the Ministry is going to keep mum on it, because she was their fault.
3. **Quirrel**

   No students were harmed because of this... aside from of course, Harry. The Quirrel incident was a case of a DADA teacher having an unfortunate end.... something which had been happening for many years at that point, because of the curse on the position. Dumbledore knew the cause of it; nobody at the Ministry did. The Ministry was not going to shut down the school because they knew nothing of what had happened.
4. **Diggory**

   The Triwizard Tournament was a historically dangerous competition that *always* ended in death, which was why it was discontinued in the first place. Since the Ministry decided to reinstate it, it is again on their heads that the death happened... since, of course, they refuse to acknowledge that Voldemort was back and had killed Cedric. This was again the Ministry's fault, not Hogwarts's.
5. **Voldemort's return**

   Of course, for quite a while, everyone refused to believe that old Voldy was back. They weren't going to do anything aside from perhaps sack Dumbledore for being a loony for claiming he was back.
   After they finally accepted that he was back, though, everyone knew that Dumbledore was the only wizard that Voldemort had ever feared. It was much safer for the children to be in a place with the most powerful wizard of all time, who Voldemort fears, along with a host of highly powerful and capable wizards (the teachers) than for them to be at home with their parents.
6. **The DADA position**

   I'll admit, it is unclear why the DADA position wasn't discontinued after it was clear that something would happen to the teacher every year. But as long as there wasn't any danger to the students, Dumbledore wasn't going to stop such an important subject, and the Ministry didn't start interfering until Harry's fifth year, as they respected Dumbledore and didn't want to cross him. For instance, after it came out that Lupin was a werewolf, he immediately resigned, so they had no reason to take action.
7. **The Battle of Hogwarts**

   This was the final, pivotal battle in a war against the worst Dark wizard of all time. Voldemort attacked the school, and they defended it... and defeated him. It came at a high cost, but instead of being the place where students died in a Voldemort attack, it became the place where Voldemort was defeated by the people of Hogwarts. It isn't the school's fault that they were attacked; so why should they get shut down, especially after the attacker was dead? After Voldemort was defeated, all of the school's troubles were over.

Comment: Re: Umbridge, there's also the complication that for a long time _Harry himself_ refused to report the abuse and consciously decided to hide his injuries out of a misplaced sense of pride. I get the impression from later books that it may well have been unknown by anyone beside Harry's friends, the Order, Fudge and Scrimgeour that Umbridge engaged in physical abuse above and beyond her stated intention (never actually acted upon, IIRC) to re-instate some of the older punishments that Filch was so enamored of.

Comment: Why "ugh" Umbridge? In muggle world corporal punishment in schools was outlawed in UK only in 1986, and in US it is still legal in 1/3 of the country. It's a perfectly traditional, "conservative" thing to do. In Hogwarts corporal punishment was practiced not too long ago, but was banned by Dumbledore. Still, this is probably a policy, not a matter of law (as Filch keeps "chains well-oiled, just in case"). In other respects, Umbridge is highly effective: after all, she correctly identified both Trelawney and Hagrid as not qualified for their positions.

Comment: @Pasha, well, except of course, for the fact that both Trelawney and Hagrid were, despite being 'unorthodox', *more* than qualified for their positions.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman well, Trelawney couldn't actually teach. Yes she was a Seer, but most of her lessons were a show, and even Hermione finally abandoned them.

Comment: But for Cedric's part, it was Hogwarts call to close the school not the ministry

Comment: @Pasha Corporal punishment in the UK never included things like forcing a student to carve lines into their own flesh...

Comment: @Ruslan, Trelawney not only could, but *did* teach.  Even in the Potterverse, where magic is real, divination was an 'art', not a 'science'.  Most could not do it, regardless of how much training they received in the theory & practice.

Comment: 'After Voldemort was defeated, all of the school's troubles were over.' --> sounds like what people might've said after both the 1st book/movie and the 2nd book/movie.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is simple: you don't close such an old institution like that, especially with how little outside supervision there seems​ to be, whether from inside or outside the magical world. Plus, everyone wants to keep it open anyway.

The Ministry of Magic seems to be doing very little in the ways of checks and controls over Hogwarts, leaving Dumbledore to his own devices most of the time. They are more concerned with preventing Muggles and the world at large to know about magic, than to reign in the wizards themselves.

Besides, it's Hogwarts, *THE* school of magic in the UK, one of the oldest, if not the oldest wizard school in the world. Generations upon generations of wizards were educated there, and the place is more or less alive and magic on its own. It's more than a school, it's a living symbol. And you don't get rid of living symbols that easily.

Plus, everyone wants to keep it open: Dumbledore to train young wizards, and especially Harry, in prevision of Voldemort's return, and Voldemort to train a new generation of wizards to serve him and do his bidding. He did want to run it with only one House, after all, the one he was part of when he was being trained there himself.

As for why it was reopened after the Battle of Hogwarts, you only need to compare it to the Battle of Britain in WWII and the damages done by Nazi bombers and V1 to London. There's a big parallel there: Londoners stayed and rebuilt after the war, even the Queen stayed at Buckingham Palace during the air raids, despite fear for her safety.

It's the same thing here: despite all the horrible things that happened, the wizards will rebuild and resume their lives as normal, in defiance of adversity.

Comment: Not to mention there isn't really a replacement for Hogwarts. If, say, UCLA had to close its main campus because of a giant superhero fight, there are other campuses, other universities, etc. that could handle the overflow. But unless they're going to ship all the students to France, there's really nowhere *but* Hogwarts.

Answer (score 8):

### What's the alternative?

Hogwarts is not the best or most respectable or most traditional or most preferable school for wizarding kids, it's the *only* wizarding school in the region.

The decision to shut down Hogwarts is not equivalent to a decision to shut down a particular school or other institution in our world - Hogwarts is not just a school, it constitutes the whole educational system in the region. The decision to shut down it down is equivalent to shutting down all schools in the country.

It's a decision that *might* be taken in some circumstances, but it raises the bar much higher, and explains why Hogwarts wasn't shut down in circumstances when an equivalent muggle school would have - in the muggle case, the alternative is to send the kids to some other school; in the Hogwarts case it means a whole generation of wizards that's (at best) homeschooled except for those who can afford to ship their kids to France or USA or whatever.

In real life, if it becomes obvious that the education system in some country is systematically bad and has dangers or horrible abuse (we have real life precedent), then the response is not to shut the whole system down - what *does* happen in such cases is reform, changing policies, possibly changing leaders, and replacing employees who don't fit the new policies or the new leaders. That's exactly what has been done in response to the events at Hogwarts.

Comment: Good points except for the "can afford to ship their kids elsewhere" bit.  They're wizards.  A trip to France or USA or whatever is as cheap as touching a portkey or any number of other magical means of transport.  (Yes, we saw wizards traveling by steamship in the Fantastic Beasts movies, but that's only because they were trying to avoid notice.)  There is, of course, a potential language barrier going to some countries, but that's not an issue between UK and US at least.  There may also be limited space at these other schools, which would explain it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I'm referring less to the expense of transportation, but more to the expense of getting the kids accepted to the schools - like with real education systems, if UK just decided to close down all schools and ship them off elsewhere (e.g. USA), that elsewhere wouldn't just accept all these students with no funding attached. Hogwarts is the educational system of magical UK+Ireland, so it gets funded by the local ministry of magic, and accepts kids of "local taxpayers", not everyone else. Accepting ex-Hogwarts students is a national-level political decision, just as closing Hogwarts.

Answer (score 1):

At first, **because Dumbledore didn't decide so, and the parents trust him**. And after Umbridge takes office, **because the people in charge don't care enough**, or worse (later in the story). And why (in the sense of, why does JK Rowling “let that happen?”) **It's all political commentary.**

To demonstrate this, **consider the motivation for wizards having a public administration (Hogwarts, but also the Ministry of Magic) in the first place**. Having no issue with basic needs (shelter, food, clothing) being met thanks to magic, a society of wizards doesn't have to raise taxes, build and maintain infrastructure, create a military force etc. The Ministry of Magic therefore has a much narrower focus than a Muggle government (that's why there is only one such Ministry). What would wizards need a government *for*, then? Broadly speaking, to maintain the peace: to prevent a Dark Lord from ever rising to power again (hence, aurors, the “Unforgivable” part in Unforgivable Curses, Azkaban and the whole judicial apparatus), and to make sure the kids are taught to fend off for themselves (hence Hogwarts, the Decree for the Reasonable Restriction of Underage Sorcery, and the whole Defense Against Dark Arts song and dance, useless as it turns out to be).

**The fact that many, if not most of these institutions fail or backfire, at least for a time, is of course [an Aesop](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnAesop)** which parallels the real world; e.g. dementors “protecting” Hogwarts are an obvious (and timely) commentary on the dangers of throwing away [liberty for the illusion of safety](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Benjamin_Franklin#1750s) in the face of terrorism / boogeyman du jour. But again like in the real world, **the wizards' nation of the British Isles doesn't just give up and throw away its institutions in the face of such setbacks**, nor (as has been commented elsewhere already) is it as risk-averse for their kids as modern Western parents are. Regarding Hogwarts specifically, it can be argued that **Dumbledore's personal prestige and past actions in the service of wizardry peace** (albeit in a rather... personal style, as befits a wizard of course) **are enough of a guarantee** for parents to grant him what amounts to a direct, if untold, mandate; despite what the Ministry of Magic (at some point) would like parents to believe, he wields much more personal authority and political clout than a head-of-education kind of public servant in a democracy — A quite British notion of legitimacy and government indeed!

Of course, that mandate fades after Rita Skeeter's smear campaign (another fairly transparent Aesop regarding the responsibility of the press), and the time when things start to *really* go sideways for Howgarts (to the point that neither the elder Weasley brothers, nor Harry Potter and his close friends, bother to attend anymore) is when a regular, “apolitical” public-servant kind of personality, who hates children by her own admission, is appointed in Dumbledore's stead. Long before Voldemort basically turns the entire institution into traitors to their own cause, that administration makes Defense Against Dark Arts teaching useless, waters down grades, makes a mockery of its own misuse of the rule of law etc. while the Ministry propaganda machine is in full force to downplay the actual dangers and keep the kids in a school that doesn't benefit them anymore. Again, the parallel with the real world couldn't be more obvious.